# How can I change ColorPrimaryDark for just one activity?

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to change the color of ColorPrimaryDark for just one activity. How can I do this?

I think go to the styles.xml and change this:

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue</item>
```

But the problem is if I do this I change the color of all my activities and I just need to change the color of one activity.

Thank you for your help!

To be specific, this color is the color of the bar at the top of the app I mean above of `ActionBar`. I use Kotlin to do this.

Comment: This might inspire you: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#Inheritance

Comment: Can you post your styles.xml?

Comment: you can define a new style that defines its parent as the common style in your app and in it redefine colorPrimaryDark. Use this new style for this specific activity

Answer (score 8):

[Create a theme](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) specifically for that `Activity`.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/gray</item>
    <!-- Your application theme -->
</style>

<style name="BlueActivityTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

Then in your manifest, apply the theme to only that `Activity`:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.app.BlueActivity"
    android:theme="@style/BlueActivityTheme"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create your own theme. Notice that I hace a new theme in **styles.xml** named MyTheme and I set the `colorPrimaryDark` to `lightGreen`.

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/lightGreen</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Now in **manifest.xml**, you have to set your theme on `activity` tag. Do not set your theme in `application` tag.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" >

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".OtherActivity1"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" />
    <activity android:name=".OtherActivity2"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity android:name=".OtherActivity3"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

</application>
```

Now, as you can see I have set custom theme which is `MyTheme` on `OtherActivity1`. For the the rest of the activity I set the theme as the default theme. Hope it helps.

Comment: I am writing an app for with minSdkVersion 19 and targetSdkVersion 26. There is no "android:theme" property for the activity element in the manifest.xml. Are there any workarounds ?

Comment: Okay. Even though the IDE complained that there was no "android:theme" it worked fine in the app. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in your activity to set the status bar color programmatically:

```
getWindow.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color));
```

Also, you can set the status bar color by writing theme in `styles.xml` file:

```
<style name="YourActivityTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/yourColor</item>
</style>
```

Then in the manifest file, you have to add the below code:

```
<activity android:name="packageName.YourActivity"
    android:theme="@style/YourActivityTheme"/>
```

Comment: What's the superclass of the getWindow() method? It's in red here.

Answer (score 0):

In /res/value/styles.xml you can define as many styles as you want, then on the root item of your activity layout xml you can use:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 style="@style/MySecondStyle"
 ....
```

Style can be assigned in the manifest too.

Even you can change style for only one View or one ViewGroup, using theme attribute, for example:

```
 <TextView       
        android:theme="@style/MyThirdStyle"
        .....
```