# How to change color PrimaryDark to color White?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

[[image][image: 2]]

How to change color Primary Dark to color White????

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change ColorPrimaryDark for just one activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45422761/how-can-i-change-colorprimarydark-for-just-one-activity)

Comment: no ..change color PrimaryDark to color White ex::https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHDpt.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are talking about the **white(light) status bar**, you can do this by adding these line in your **theme**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
</style>
```

But it will only work for **SDK>=23**

Comment: it Working Thanks for u